# Pandas Data Frame calculations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like the following one.

| index | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 |
| 2 | 250 |
| 3 | 280 |

How can I do the following table: by subtracting index3-index2,index2-index1,index1-nan like this

| index | values | values2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 | 234 |
| 2 | 250 | 16 |
| 3 | 280 | 30 |

for solving this I used `df.diff()`, but I can't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this using `shift` as well

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [10, 20, 15, 30, 45]},
                  index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-01-05"))

df['col2'] = (df['Col1'] - df['Col1'].shift(1)).fillna(df['Col1'])

print(df)
```

Which gives this output:

```
            Col1  col2
2020-01-01    10  10.0
2020-01-02    20  10.0
2020-01-03    15  -5.0
2020-01-04    30  15.0
2020-01-05    45  15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use `diff`:

```
s = df['values'].diff()
df['values'] = df['values'].where(s.isna(), s)
```

output:

```
   index  values
0      1     234
1      2      16
2      3      30
```

Alternative:

```
df['values'] = df['values'].diff().fillna(df['values'][0])
```